# Visual Studio Code does not suggest any Node.js syntax

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I am new to visual studio code and Node.js and also install Node and npm to my computer.
My problem is VS code does not suggest any node syantax.
I watch youtube tutorials to learn node and in the video, instructors VS code suggest node js syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Based on: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense it should have intellisense come right out of the box within VS code. I would recommend uninstalling and reinstalling VS code.

Some other gotcha's or things which may help:

- Intellisense for javascript only works within files that are labeled with the `.js` extension
- The hotkey Ctrl+Shift+`brings up a terminal which contains a`Problems` in there you can see the problems of the Workspace which may show some additional information regarding what is failing.